# Celery Worker Database Connection Pooling

Tags: python, postgresql, connection-pooling, celery

I am using Celery standalone (not within Django).  I am planning to have one worker task type running on multiple physical machines.  The task does the following

1. Accept an XML document.
2. Transform it.
3. Make **multiple** database reads and writes.

I'm using PostgreSQL, but this would apply equally to other store types that use connections.  In the past, I've used a database connection pool to avoid creating a new database connection on every request or avoid keeping the connection open too long.  However, since each Celery worker runs in a separate process, I'm not sure how they would actually be able to share the pool.  Am I missing something?  I know that Celery allows you to persist a result returned from a Celery worker, but that is not what I'm trying to do here.  Each task can do several different updates or inserts depending on the data processed.

What is the right way to access a database from within a Celery worker?

Is it possible to share a pool across multiple workers/tasks or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Did you solve it? I would be interested in a solution.

Comment: I went with one db connection per worker.

Comment: @oneself It would be nice if you accepted an answer

Comment: Hi how did you get one db connection for every worker. I would be interested in the solution

Answer (score 44):

I like tigeronk2's idea of one connection per worker. As he says, Celery maintains its own pool of workers so there really isn't a need for a separate database connection pool.  The [Celery Signal docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-signals) explain how to do custom initialization when a worker is created so I added the following code to my tasks.py and it seems to work exactly like you would expect. I was even able to close the connections when the workers are shutdown:

```
from celery.signals import worker_process_init, worker_process_shutdown

db_conn = None

@worker_process_init.connect
def init_worker(**kwargs):
    global db_conn
    print('Initializing database connection for worker.')
    db_conn = db.connect(DB_CONNECT_STRING)


@worker_process_shutdown.connect
def shutdown_worker(**kwargs):
    global db_conn
    if db_conn:
        print('Closing database connectionn for worker.')
        db_conn.close()
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on this one. Doesn't this create a connection on the module level, so for each `celery worker`? And if you access the global `db_conn` from within a task, you're reusing the same connection in multiple processes or threads (depending on your concurrency settings.). It will start many connections, but just overwrite the connection with every new worker that's initiated. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yep, that's the point:  one connection per worker.  This was a solution for a pool of worker processes and, in that case, the global db_conn is only global within the context of a process so it all plays nice.  It's been a while so I don't remember if I even bothered to test it with threads.

Comment: @ThatAintWorking This worked beautifully for me with pyodbc.

Comment: The downside of it is that, if you have fixed number of workers, the idle worker's db connection can become stale and invalid.

Comment: I used same approach instead of using global, I stored my into app.conf['my_object'] = MyObject(), and then used task.

Answer (score 3):

Have one DB connection per worker process. Since celery itself maintains a pool of worker processes, your db connections will always be equal to the number of celery workers. 
Flip side, sort of, it will tie up db connection pooling to celery worker process management. But that should be fine given that GIL allows only one thread at a time in a process.

Comment: "[..] Since celery itself maintains a pool of worker processes [..]" Do you have a link to the docs?

Comment: Ah sorry, I was more aiming for the "one DB connection per worker process" part. But that doesn't seem to be part of the docs. Pretty annoying, seems like a very important thing to me.

Comment: @user1252307 The place where you do this kind of thing is described in the docs. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default behavior to have threaded workers instead of a worker per process in your celery config:

`CELERYD_POOL = "celery.concurrency.threads.TaskPool"`

Then you can store the shared pool instance on your task instance and reference it from each threaded task invocation.

Comment: Aren't Python threads something people usually try to avoid using?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. Threading works fine in python for I/O bound processes. It's only if you are CPU intensive that you might run into trouble with the GAL.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, [celery.concurrency.gevent](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.concurrency.gevent.html#celery-concurrency-gevent) could provide the pool sharing and not aggravate the GIL.  However, it's support is still "experimental".

And a [psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html#psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool) to share amongst greenlets (coroutines) which will all run in a single process/thread.

Tiny bit of other [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194064/using-celery-on-processes-and-gevent-in-tasks-at-the-same-time) discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [pgbouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer). For celery nothing should change and the connection pooling is done outside of the processes. I have the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642999/celery-keep-database-connection-open-with-pgbouncer).

*('perhaps' because I am not sure if there could be any side effects)*

Comment: A side effect would be running into SQLAlchemy's max connections per process default https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#error-3o7r

Answer (score 0):

Contribute back my findings by implementing and monitoring.

Welcome feedback.

Reference:
use pooling http://www.prschmid.com/2013/04/using-sqlalchemy-with-celery-tasks.html

Each worker process (prefork mode specified by -c k) will establish one new connection to DB without pooling or reusing.
So if using pooling, the pool is seen only at each worker process level. So pool size > 1 is not useful, but reusing connection is still fine for saving connection from open & close.

If using one connection per worker process, 1 DB connection is established per worker process (prefork mode celery -A app worker -c k) at initialization phase.
It saves connection from open & close repeatedly.

No matter how many worker thread (eventlet), each worker thread (celery -A app worker -P eventlet) only establish one connection to DB without pooling or reusing.
So for eventlet, all worker threads (eventlets) on one celery process (celery -A app worker ...) have 1 db connection at each moment.

According to celery docs

> but you need to ensure your tasks do not perform blocking calls, as
>   this will halt all other operations in the worker until the blocking
>   call returns.

It is probably due to the way of MYSQL DB connection is blocking calls.