# InterfaceError: connection already closed

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, celery, psycopg2

I'm running a `celery(4.1.0)` task with `django(1.11.6)` using `psycopg2(2.7.3)`, getting these errors after 5-6 hour of deploying the app on production. [One of the related issue on `Django` issue tickets](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15802). Tried various solution of reconnecting the connection using try and except, handling `InterfaceError`. Any help will be appreciated. Checked and Applied some of the solutions, but nothing seems to be working, [Celery Worker Database Connection Pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526249/celery-worker-database-connection-pooling)

### Traceback

```
InterfaceError: connection already closed
  File "billiard/pool.py", line 358, in workloop
    result = (True, prepare_result(fun(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 537, in _fast_trace_task
    uuid, args, kwargs, request,
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 482, in trace_task
    I, _, _, _ = on_error(task_request, exc, uuid)
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 330, in on_error
    task, request, eager=eager, call_errbacks=call_errbacks,
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 164, in handle_error_state
    call_errbacks=call_errbacks)
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 212, in handle_failure
    task.on_failure(exc, req.id, req.args, req.kwargs, einfo)
  File "telemetry/tasks.py", line 29, in on_failure
    save_failed_task(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)
  File "telemetry/celery_failure.py", line 46, in save_failed_task
    existing_task_first = existing_task.first()
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 564, in first
    objects = list((self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1])
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 882, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 220, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

Comment: Not really but the main cause of the error was longer running transactions, Mostly blocking ones.