# Celery Worker don't execute cassandra queries

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra, redis, celery

I'm using

```
celery == 4.1.0 (latentcall)
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Python 2.7.14
```

I'm trying to execute Cassandra Query in Celery worker function. But Celery worker received task but not execute Query.

**`tasks.py`**

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('<workername>', backend="rpc://", broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
dbSession = Cluster().connect()


@app.tasks()
def get_data():
    query = "SELECT * FROM customers"
    CustomerObj = dbSession.execute(dbSession.prepare(query))

    return CustomerObj


get_data.delay()
```

I start worker using :

```
$ celery worker -A <worker_name> -l INFO -c 1

 -------------- celery@ubuntu v4.1.0 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.13.0-21-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-17.10-artful 2018-04-20 14:31:41
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         Woker:0x7fa4a0e6f310
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . Worker.get_data

[2018-04-20 14:31:41,271: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2018-04-20 14:31:41,285: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-04-20 14:31:42,315: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
.............
[2018-04-20 14:31:42,332: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ubuntu ready.
[2018-04-20 14:31:43,823: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: <worker_name>.get_data[8de91fdf-1388-4d5c-bb22-8cb00c1c065e]
```

Worker process is just stopped there.It will not execute that SELECT query and give any data.

Anyone suggest me How can I run this code to execute Cassandra Queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't define `dbSession` globally. 
Celery task can run in different workers, so the connection can't be global.

I can suggest two options:

1. Create the session within the task. It should work. The pros is that you'll create new session per each task. Maybe `lazy` (`@LazyProperty`) should help here.
2. You can create the connection in the worker level: try to create your session when worker start, maybe with `worker_init` signal ([ref](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-init)). The problem here is that you can have `concurrency` level > 1 (depends how you start the worker) - and than you need pool of sessions to serve more than one celery task at a time (handle more than one Cassandra session at a time).

By the way you should use the `global` keyword in python. If you are running one instance it may fix too.

Here is a related question that might help you: [Celery Worker Database Connection Pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526249/celery-worker-database-connection-pooling)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since celery doesn't use the application's connection instance. Initiate a new connection at celery initiation. the below snippet is as per Cassandra documentation for celery

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_process_init, beat_init
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
from cassandra.cqlengine.connection import (
    cluster as cql_cluster, session as cql_session)

def cassandra_init(**kwargs):
    """ Initialize a clean Cassandra connection. """
    if cql_cluster is not None:
        cql_cluster.shutdown()
    if cql_session is not None:
        cql_session.shutdown()
    connection.setup()

# Initialize worker context for both standard and periodic tasks.
worker_process_init.connect(cassandra_init)
beat_init.connect(cassandra_init)

app = Celery()
```

This worked for me